# why for structure with flexible array member, we shouldn't use structure assignment for copying

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm currently learning c structure, especially structure with flexible array member.

Given a structure flexible array

```
struct flex
{
    size_t count;
    double average;
    double scores[]; // flexible array member
};
```

I have been told not to use assignment for copying

[image]

I'm not sure why this operation only copy the non-flexible member of  the structure.

Could someone please explain to me the underlying reasons why this is the case?

Comment: Ask yourself: How would the assignment-operator know the **actual** size of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the structure doesn’t count the FAM. The compiler has no way to know how big the FAM is.  Consequently, any copy ignores the FAM.  Since that’s very seldom the desired behaviour, don’t use structure copying on structures with a FAM.